# How to check if email already exists in database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know how to check if email already exists in the database. (MySQL)

I need the code for checking. (I type this because i need more characters on my stackoverflow posting)

If you're helpful,i will be happy.

Yeah,i must type more characters.

PHP:

````php
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["register-user"])) {
    /* Form Required Field Validation */
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $error_message = "Trebuie sa completezi tot.";
        break;
        }
    }
    /* Password Matching Validation */
    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']){ 
    $error_message = 'Parolele trebuie sa fie la fel!<br>'; 
    }

    /* Email Validation */
    if(!isset($error_message)) {
        if (!filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error_message = "Adresa invalida de email.";
        }
    }

    /* Validation to check if gender is selected */
    if(!isset($error_message)) {
    if(!isset($_POST["gender"])) {
    $error_message = "Toate campurile sunt obligatorii!";
    }
    }

    /* Validation to check if Terms and Conditions are accepted */
    if(!isset($error_message)) {
        if(!isset($_POST["terms"])) {
        $error_message = "Trebuie sa accepti termenii si conditiile!";
        }
    }

    if(!isset($error_message)) {
        require_once("dbcontroller.php");
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "INSERT INTO utilizatori (user_name, first_name, last_name, password, email, gender) VALUES
        ('" . $_POST["userName"] . "', '" . $_POST["firstName"] . "', '" . $_POST["lastName"] . "', '" . md5($_POST["password"]) . "', '" . $_POST["userEmail"] . "', '" . $_POST["gender"] . "')";
        $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
        if(!empty($result)) {
            $error_message = "";
            $success_message = "Te-ai inregistrat cu succes!";  
            unset($_POST);
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problema cu inregistrarea,contacteaza administratorii!";  
        }
    }
}
?>```
````

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/check_value

Comment: I wish some new version of PHP would have a message that can't be removed echoed to the client/user when the code is unsafe. Preferably it would be rolled out to older versions too.

Comment: And MD5 for passwords isn't that great either.

Comment: Coming back to the question make emails a unique key, so that identical email want be inserted abymore.

ALTER TABLE `utilizatori` ADD UNIQUE `unique_email`(`email`); and of course all abouve

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` statement to `INSERT INTO SELECT ...`

with `email != '" . $_POST["userEmail"] . "'`

```
INSERT INTO utilizatori (user_name, first_name, last_name, password, email, gender) 
SELECT
 '" . $_POST["userName"] . "', '" . $_POST["firstName"] . "', '" . $_POST["lastName"] . "', 
  '" . md5($_POST["password"]) . "', '" . $_POST["userEmail"] . "', '" . $_POST["gender"] . "'
  FROM utilizatori 
 WHERE email != '" . $_POST["userEmail"] . "'
```

*I don't know about the precautions against injection within php, but in Database at least we keep SQL statements inside procedures/functions to be prevented from injections.*